# Checking for words in a loop

Tags: java, swing, loops

So I have this project for my computer class and I can't seem to get my program to run no matter how many different ways I try it. What I'm trying to do is have the program check if what the user types equals any of the three words (Cookies, Milk, Both) and if it doesn't ask the question again and use that input but since I'm new to java I can't seem to get it to work

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Cookie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Info info = new Info();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

static class Info {

        String inputs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "What do you want, Cookies, Milk or Both?");
        String word1 = "Cookies";
        String word2 = "milk";
        String word3 = "Both";
        String flagger = "";
        while (true)
            if(inputs.length() !=0) {
            }
                for(int i=0; i<inputs.length(); i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<word1.length(); j++)
                    {
                        if(inputs.charAt(i)==word1.charAt(j))
                        {
                            flagger=flagger+word1.charAt(i)+"";
                        }
                    }

                    for(int j=0; j<word2.length(); j++)
                    {
                        if(inputs.charAt(i)==word2.charAt(j))
                        {
                            flagger=flagger+word2.charAt(i)+"";
                        }
                    }
                    for(int j=0; j<word3.length(); j++)
                    {
                        if(inputs.charAt(i)==word3.charAt(j))
                        {
                            flagger=flagger+word3.charAt(i)+"";
                        }
                    }    
                if(!(inputs.equalsIgnoreCase(flagger))) {
                    String message = String.format("%s", "Huh, I didn't get that, please say it again");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
                    String inputs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "What do you want, Cookies, Milk or Both?");

                }

                if(inputs.equalsIgnoreCase("cookies")) {
                    String message = String.format("%s", "Here have some Cookies :)");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
                }

                if(inputs.equalsIgnoreCase("MILK")) {
                    String message = String.format("%s", "Here is the Milk you wanted :)");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
                }

                if(inputs.equalsIgnoreCase("BOTH")) {
                    String message = String.format("%s", "Here is your Cookies and Milk :)");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please explain 'I can't seem to get it to work' ? What's the problem, what's expected, do you have any error while compiling ?

Comment: Guys down scoring the question is not very nice.. This person may not be great at explaining, that is why we ask him.. He could be tired and in a bind for a deadline. If you do not want to help him fine, do not be mean unless he shows no initiative at all. That said, like JFPicard asked we need a bit more details to help with you problem.

Comment: `if(inputs.length() !=0) {}` o.0

Answer (score 3):

I was able to compile your code after making few fixes. I have used a different approach, this is working, at least for most of the scenarios.

> Here's my Cookie.java

```
public class Cookie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Info info = new Info();
            info.checkInput();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

> And Info.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Info {

    public void checkInput() {
        String inputs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "What do you want, Cookies, Milk or Both?");

        Map<String, String> words = new HashMap<String, String>();
        words.put("cookies", "Here have some Cookies :)");
        words.put("milk", "Here is the Milk you wanted :)");
        words.put("both", "Here is your Cookies and Milk :)");

        while (true) {

            if (inputs != null && inputs.length() > 0) {

                if (words.containsKey(inputs.toLowerCase())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            words.get(inputs.toLowerCase()));
                    inputs = repeat();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Huh, I didn't get that, please say it again");
                    inputs = repeat();
                }
            } else {
                inputs = repeat();          }
        }
    }

    private String repeat() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "What do you want, Cookies, Milk or Both?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You code didn't work because:

- you try to use static class Info, like a method - you declare inner static method with some class fields, and then just add code like in method, this is why it will not even compile. You can change it on static or nonstatic method, or add some methods to it. For example change `static class Info` on `static void Info(){`, and call it by just `Info()` (insted of `Info info = new Info();` in `main` method.
- you multiple times declare `String inputs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What do you want, Cookies, Milk or Both?");`, it is enough to use just `inputs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What do you want, Cookies, Milk or Both?");` second time.
- you mixed some brackets, like in:

  ```
  while (true)
      if(inputs.length() !=0) {
      }  // this is problematic bracket
  ```

  so it will not work at all, and all nested if statments with it.

You need to fix it to at least run your application.

**EDIT**

It seems that you have a lot of unnecessary code, you can shorten it for example to:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cookie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true){
            String inputs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "What do you want, Cookies, Milk or Both?");
            if(inputs.equalsIgnoreCase("cookies")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here have some Cookies :)");
                break;
            }else if(inputs.equalsIgnoreCase("MILK")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is the Milk you wanted :)");
                break;
            }else if(inputs.equalsIgnoreCase("BOTH")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is your Cookies and Milk :)");
                break;
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Huh, I didn't get that, please say it again");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to get input from the user, and compare it to some preset strings (cookies, milk, and both)
What if you put the whole thing into a `while(true)` loop, and after getting the input from the user, you wrote something like

```
String message;
Boolean isValid = true;
if (inputs.equalsIgnoreCase("Cookies")){
message = "Have some cookies";
}
...
else{
message = "Try again";
isValid = false;
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
if(isValid) break;
```

Note: I'm writing this on a mobile, so syntax may not be exact. Use your discretion.